# factory pattern in F#

Tags: f#

With this type:

```
   let Empty =
        {
            Buy = new Dictionary<int64, int64 * float>()
            Sell = new Dictionary<int64, int64 * float>()
        }
```

if I assign it to several entities through the code:

```
let a = Empty
let b = Empty
```

they'll represent the same dictionaries.

How can I generate a new instance every time?

Comment: Just make it a function. `() => ...`.

Comment: of course.. I can see the lack of sleep is getting to me :D thanks!

Comment: Me too, that wasn't even close to F# syntax! But I hope you still get the point :D

Comment: haha, yes, no worries

Comment: @glennsl Make that an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a factory pattern for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let makeEmpty () = {
    Buy = new Dictionary<int64, int64 * float>()
    Sell = new Dictionary<int64, int64 * float>()
}
```